# <Xamarin> How to access parameters passed to testcloud.exe with "--test-params [cspairs] " in command line?

Tags: c#, testing, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-test-cloud

Description according to "test-cloud.exe help submit":

**--test-params [cspairs] - Additional test paramaters, format is comma-separated key:value pairs**

I want to pass parameters to my tests by using that command.

Now how can I access these parameters inside the Tests.cs file?

If it's not possible, then is there any other way I can add parameters to my Test Cloud tests and then read them inside Tests.cs file?

Comment: For the sake of future Users/Viewers, can you please review the answer below.  If you feel it answers your question, please upvote and mark it as `Answered`  :)

Answer (score 0):

Are parameters available to the test.cs file?

Unfortunately, No.  Well, at least not at this time...

The parameters are currently only used for test setup.  Although, that does sound like a nice enhancement.  Perhaps you could share your idea on the XTC Ideas & Feature Requests page?  From there, other Users like yourself can vote on which features are most important to you, helping the XTC team plot their roadmap with future features.  Here is a link to the XTC Ideas & Feature Requests page - https://testcloud.ideas.aha.io/

=======================

**Note for other viewers of this page:**
It is possible to see of the all available command line parameters by running the following:

- OSX – `mono packages/Xamarin.UITest.X.X.X/tools/test-cloud.exe help submit`
- Windows – `packages\Xamarin.UITest.X.X.X\tools\test-cloud help submit`

**Current List of parameters** *(as of 1/12/2017)*

*(copied from [XTC: Submitting UITests at the Command Line](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/submitting-tests-at-command-line/#Submitting_UITests))*

`--assembly-dir <PATH>` The path to the folder holding the test assemblies.

`--devices <DEVICE ID>` The device ID that was provided in the Test Cloud Upload dialog.

`--user <EMAIL>`    The e-mail address of the team member submitting the tests.

`--nunit-xml <FILENAME>`    The filename to which test results are exported, formatted as NUnit results XML. Optional.

`--sign-info <FILENAME>`    Android only. Supply a signing information file that will be used to sign the Test Server APK. See the section below for more details. Optional.

`--dsym <FILENAME>` iOS only. Will upload the dSYM files along with the application and tests. This allows for more detail in the log files. Optional.

`--fixture <NUNIT-FIXTURE>` NUnit fixture / namespace to run. (Can be used multiple times)

`--include <CATEGORY-NAME>` Identifies the NUnit test categories that should only be included in the test run.

`--exclude <CATEGORY-NAME>` Identifies the NUnit test categories that should be excluded from the test run.

`--test-chunk`  Run tests in parallel by method

`--fixture-chunk`   Run tests in parallel by fixture

`--data <FILE OR DIRECTORY>`    Uploads file or directory along with assemblies. (Can be used multiple times).

Comment: Additional Resource - XTC Cheat Sheet - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/cheatsheet/